# Persistent shared memory post process-termination winapi

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

I'm looking to do something like mapped shared memory (CreateFileMapping()), but I want the virtual file to live on after the process terminates and be readable by other processes until I explicitly delete it.

The application is related to storing passwords, so I don't want to use a physical file or other easily readable persistent methods (like registry).  I'd like to pump the data into memory, keep it there until deleted, and read from it when needed.  It should disappear on reboot.

Comment: This is going to give you the illusion of security, at the cost of extra complexity for you.

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the wheel. You could just as well use the [PasswordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential) class to store your passwords, and benefit from professional grade security without trying to roll your own.

Comment: Yeah ... actually that is the wheel I (didn't realize I) was reinventing.  Thanks for pointing me at that.  The discussion is really great, though, since it's good to know that there are other ways to poke data into persistent shared memory with a permanent handle.  Thanks, everyone, for the direction.  I was able to get this working after setting SeCreatePermanentPrivilege

Comment: The handle is a reference to the Section object. You're not making the handle permanent. You're making the Section permanent, which is possible because it's named in the object namespace. The permanent flag prevents the kernel's Object Manager from deleting the name, which in turn keeps the object referenced.

Comment: FYI, if you're not creating the Section in a service or task in session 0, then use the "Global" link, e.g. `L"Global\\SectionName"` (backslash only; forward slash is a name character). Windows creates named kernel objects relative to a [`RootDirectory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_object_attributes) handle for your session's named objects directory, "\Sessions\\[session identifier]\BaseNamedObjects", and "Global" is a SymbolicLink object in that directory that reparses to the session 0 "\BaseNamedObjects" global object directory.

Answer (score 3):

When a process terminates, any kernel handles it still has open are automatically closed by the OS.  So, the only way a memory mapping object will be able to live on is if another process has an open handle to the same mapping object.  When all processes have closed their handles to the mapping object, it goes away completely.

You might consider creating a separate service app to run in the background and allocate the actual memory object, and then let processes share the memory object while the service is running.

Otherwise, to truly allocate a block of memory that persists until reboot, regardless of who allocates it, you can use a RAM disk and store the data in a "file" in RAM, where each process can open the "file" when needed.  When the machine reboots, RAM is wiped clean.

Putting the data in memory is no safer than storing it in a file or in the Registry, though.  If you are worried about security, just encrypt the data and decrypt it when needed.

Comment: Yup ... I thought about forking a new process and having it hold the file map, but I didn't want to hold a process just to keep shared memory.

Shared memory is slightly safer than the registry in that regedit is much more accessible than tools to examine mapped files or shared memory (for end-users).

Is there a Win32API to create a ramfile?  The reason I didn't want to just encrypt and decrypt is that I'm passing to an external program that requires the password on the command-line.

Comment: This is correct strictly within the documented Windows API. However, the NT Object Manager does allow creating permanent objects if the caller has SeCreatePermanentPrivilege (typically a system service). Usually it's applied at creation time via the [`OBJ_PERMANENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_object_attributes) flag. An existing object can be made permanent via the undocumented call `NtMakePermanentObject(HANDLE Handle)` and then made temporary again via `NtMakeTemporaryObject`.

Comment: "*Is there a Win32API to create a ramfile?*" - no, but there are plenty of 3rd party RAM disk drivers available, and when installed, you can use standard file I/O functions. "*The reason I didn't want to just encrypt and decrypt is that I'm passing to an external program that requires the password on the command-line*" - so what's stopping you from simply decrypting the password before preparing the command-line string?

Comment: So, @eryksun - that's a great trick!  Had difficulty finding a lib entry point for NtMakePermanentObject, so I just loaded it from NTDLL.DLL.  The calls inside the DLL did not fail, but it also didn't make the handle permanent (hMapFile is the handle returned by CreateFileMapping().

`code`
  HANDLE hLibrary;
  FARPROC foo;

   hLibrary = LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
   if(!hLibrary)
     printf("bad lib");
   foo = GetProcAddress(hLibrary, "NtMakePermanentObject");
   if(!foo)
     printf("bad address");
   foo(hMapFile);
   printf("%s", GetLastError());

Comment: @ShnorW. `FARPROC` does not have the correct signature for calling `NtMakePermanentObject()`. I'm surprised `foo(hMapFile);` even compiled, it shouldn't have. Use a more appropriate typedef instead, eg: `typedef NTSTATUS NTAPI (*NTMPO)(HANDLE); NTMPO foo; foo = (NTMPO) GetProcAddress(...);` Also, you can't use `GetLastError()` with NTDLL functions. They return an `NTSTATUS` status code, so print that value instead (and you are not printing the return value of `GetLastError()` correctly anyway, as you can't use `%s` with integer values. Use `%d` for `NTSTATUS`, and `%u` for `GetLastError()`).

Comment: @ShnorW., I don't doubt that your code compiled and ran, but the call is likely failing with `STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` (0xC0000061) because you're not calling it from a SYSTEM service that has SeCreatePermanentPrivilege enabled. By default this privilege isn't granted to administrators or regular users -- though it's not very hard for an admin to impersonate a SYSTEM logon (e.g. from csrss.exe, opened with limited-query access).

Comment: *Had difficulty finding a lib* - use `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib`. and you need how minimum run as 'Administrators' for can get system process token, where SeCreatePermanentPrivilege  exist